# How to Set ImageView transparent

Tags: android

My image is set to 50% transparent. When I put it to ImageView, it is totally opaque, can't see the things behind. How can I set in xml for the ImageView 100% transparent, so that when I set the image, I can see the things behind. I tried

```
android:opacity="translucent" 
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Both of them, don't work.

Comment: What do you mean by 100% transparent? What's the need to put a picture at all in such a case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the `alpha` transparency attribute:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:alpha

```
android:alpha="0.5"
```

Will give 50% alpha transparency to the `View`.