# Getting Transparent image in android

Tags: android

I got the captured image(bitmap image) through camera content in android but I need to get 50% transparency of that image and it should be displayed on ImageView. How to do this?

Comment: Just set that image in `ImageView` and take a look at [Android and setting alpha for (image) view alpha](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931071/android-and-setting-alpha-for-image-view-alpha)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389023/how-to-set-imageview-transparent

Comment: i don't want image view as transparent.I need bitmap image as transparent because i want to make this transparent image on top of another image which should be displayed on imageview

Answer (score 1):

Set  this `android:alpha="0.5"` attribute to your `ImageView`.

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/e4"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:alpha="0.5" />
```

you can set `alpha` value between 0 to 1 for Transparency in `Imageview`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this alpha transparency attribute:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:alpha

```
android:alpha="0.5"
```

Will give you 50% alpha transparency to the View.

For ex:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Imgexample"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/example"
        android:alpha="0.5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to just display with transparency then, you simply use [ImageView's setImageAlpha](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageAlpha(int))

`imageView.setImageAlpha(int)`

Value ranges from 0-255

0 being transparent and 255 being opaque

Answer (score 0):

Try to set transparency on `ImageView` with `setAlpha(float)` method.. where `0f` is full transprent and `1f` is fully opaque.

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
myImage.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

Answer (score 0):

set `android:alpha=0.5` property for  you ImageView

refer this:

```
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.5"

         />
```

Comment: i need a transparent image lying on opaque image

Comment: I think you can achieve this using Frame Layout . refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864422/android-imageview-overlay-another-imageview.